# How to count number of unique values in column based on values in other column

Tags: r, dataframe, function, count

I have a dataframe:

```
col1    col2
1        10
1        -2
2        -4
3        5
4        8
4        17
```

I want to count number of unique values in col1, if at least once on same row there was positive value in col2. So, here answer must be 3, cause unique value 1,2,3 comply with the requirement (1 because there was case when col2 had value 10). value 2 from col1 doesn't comply requirement. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
dplyr::n_distinct(df1$col1[df1$col2 > 0])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R one-liner.

```
length(unique(df1$col1[df1$col2 > 0]))
#[1] 3
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
col1    col2
1        10
1        -2
2        -4
3        5
4        8
4        17
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` and that you mean

> So, here answer must be 3, cause unique value **1,2,4** comply with the requirement

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(col2 > 0) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(col1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% summarise(result = n_distinct(col1[col2 > 0]))

#  result
#1      3
```

Or in base R -

```
length(unique(df$col1[df$col2 > 0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this base R option

```
nrow(
  unique(
    subset(
      df,
      col2 > 0,
      select = -col2
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[1] 3
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[col2 > 0, uniqueN(col1)]
[1] 3
```